# How to test which files will be copied with the cp command?

Tags: cp, file-copy

I'm creating a simple script that copies all files from DIRECTORYA that do not exist in DIRECTORYB. I'm doing this through the use of the cp command:

```
cp -u DIRECTORYA/* DIRECTORYB
```

What I'd like to do is also send an email to an administrator that will list the files that have been copied.

So ideally, before I run the above command, I'd like to get the files that will be copied and store them in a variable for later use when building my email message.

Can anybody point me in the right direction? I've looked into using grep but I don't think this can be done with the cp command?

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but can't you use the `-v` flag, to print the filenames as they are copied? Redirect that to a file or directly in a variable and use that to build your message.

Comment: Additionally the `cp` command has option `--attributes-only` wich allow to do not copy files data, but just directory and files structure.

Comment: Sorry I'm fairly new to scripting. If I use the -v flag, how can I output to a variable instead of a file?

Comment: Assuming you are using bash, `variable=$(cp -v ...)` captures the stdout of cp. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.htm

Answer (score 7):

I don't think GNU `cp` has anything to help you if you want to see what it would do without acting. If you want to log the files that were modified, you can use the `-v` option:

```
cp -puv DIRECTORYA/* DIRECTORYB >copy.log
```

Instead of `cp`, you can use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), which is a lot more powerful and installed almost everywhere except for low-end embedded systems (and easy to install where it isn't present by default).

```
rsync -aunv DIRECTORYA/* DIRECTORYB >what-would-be-done.txt
```

or

```
rsync -auv DIRECTORYA/* DIRECTORYB >copy.log
```

Comment: I wonder if the `find` command couldn't be tailored to work like the `cp` command. I'm gonna give that a try this week. If you have any caveats in advance that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sure, you can run `find` inside both DIRECTORYA and DIRECTORYB and compare the output. I'm sure the code to do this has been posted multiple times on this site.

Comment: rsync is great, thanks this is my preferred solution.

Comment: NOTE: `rsync -aun` (aka `rsync --archive --update --dry-run`) will print nothing, you need to add the `--verbose/-v` flag to get your dry run output. Maddening, but now you know (rsync version  3.2.3  protocol version 31). rsync is still awesome.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html),

> **`-u`**, **`--update`**
>   copy only when the *SOURCE* file is *newer* than the destination
>   file or when the destination file is *missing*

this is a feature which combines two tests, one trivial to implement in a script (*missing*) and one requiring some work (*newer*).  You could make a script which reports what is needed using `comm`, `diff` and `test`.

None of the standard `cp` utilities provide the ability to dry-run a copy operation.  As suggested, `rsync` is the way to do this with a commonly-available utility.  Of course, `rsync` is usually used to copy based on more criteria than just *newer* or *missing* (file size and timestamps also are used).  But it can be reduced to doing just `cp -u`.

For non-standard utilities, there's the `copy` utility which I wrote (and of course still use) in the late 1980s.  It was probably inspired by the `make` utility, since the first option I added was `-n`.

For the given example, it would be used like this:

```
$ copy -nvU DIRECTORYA/* DIRECTORYB
** copy DIRECTORYA/foo to DIRECTORYB/foo
** 1 file would be copied, 616 bytes
```

Further reading:

- [copy - file/directory copy utility](http://invisible-island.net/ded/manpage/copy.html)

  > **`-n`**  disables the actual creation or modification of files, and (depending  on  the  level of verboseness) shows the effect which the  **`copy`**
  >   command would have.
  >   **`-u`**  copies files only if their size or modification date  differs,  and
  >   links only if the link-text differs.
  >   **`-U`**
  >   copies  only  files that are newer than the destination, or that do
  >   not exist in the destination.
- changelog entry from [August 1988](http://invisible-island.net/ded/cm_tools/CHANGES.html#t19880816):

  > ```
  > 1988-08-16    
  >         * src/copy/src/copy.c: added "-d" and "-n" options.
  > ```

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to run `cp foo*bar whatever`, then run `echo foo*bar whatever` instead.

Comment: But OP wants to run `cp -u` and he's looking for a dry-run like option for cp.

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff command. I have a job that copy some backup files everyday. some time I need to check if all files are copied, here is the syntax:

```
diff /file1/ /file2/
```

and of course if you want to copy them use:

```
cp -u /file1/* /file2
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using rsync instead. Rsync works perfectly well on local copies and can certainly do what you want, once you wade through the fifteen gazillion options it has.

```
rsync -avun DIRECTORYA/ DIRECTORYB
```

will show you everything that would be done, and

```
rsync -avu DIRECTORYA/ DIRECTORYB
```

will do it.